# What is the cgo type equivalent to a const pointer to a struct?

Tags: go, cgo

I have an extern function decalred in `C`:

```
//extern void goCallback(const struct libvlc_event_t*, void*);
```

To be defined in `go`:

```
//export goCallback
func goCallback(event unsafe.Pointer, userData unsafe.Pointer) {
    log.Fatal("TODO goCallback")
}
```

When compiling the code, I get type conflicting errors

```
# github.com/tarrsalah/libvlc-go
In file included from $WORK/github.com/tarrsalah/libvlc-go/_obj/_cgo_export.c:3:0:
cgo-gcc-export-header-prolog:42:13: error: conflicting types for ‘goCallback’
In file included from $WORK/github.com/tarrsalah/libvlc-go/_obj/_cgo_export.c:3:0:
../../../tarrsalah/libvlc-go/event_manager.go:6:13: note: previous declaration of ‘goCallback’ was here
 //extern void goCallback(const struct libvlc_event_t*, void*);
             ^~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/go-build855229382/github.com/tarrsalah/libvlc-go/_obj/_cgo_export.c:17:6: error: conflicting types for ‘goCallback’
 void goCallback(void* p0, void* p1)
      ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from $WORK/github.com/tarrsalah/libvlc-go/_obj/_cgo_export.c:3:0:
../../../tarrsalah/libvlc-go/event_manager.go:6:13: note: previous declaration of ‘goCallback’ was here
 //extern void goCallback(const struct libvlc_event_t*, void*);
             ^~~~~~~~~~
```

What is the `go` equivalent to `const struct libvlc_event_t*`?

Comment: The compiler complains because function `goCallback` defined both in `C` and in `Go`. The `//export ...` is needed when you want your `go` function to be accessible from `C`. If you want to use the `C` function from `go`, `//extern void ...` is enough.

Comment: Looking at the https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#function-variables, I'm doing it  right, accessing to a `go` from `c` requires both the `//extern declaration` and the `//export comment`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. The compiler complains because there are two `goCallback` functions with different signature. I wrote an answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create type alias to the struct with `typedef` as follows:

```
/*

typedef const struct libvlc_event_t clibvlc_event_t;
extern void goCallback(clibvlc_event_t*, void*);
*/
import "C"

//export goCallback
func goCallback(event *C.clibvlc_event_t, userData unsafe.Pointer) {
    log.Fatal("TODO goCallback")
}
```

If you want to know `go` type definition which is compatible to `C.clibvlc_event_t`, run `cgo` with `-godefs` options, i.e.

```
go tool cgo -godefs <YOUR-GO-FILE>
```

For example, if the struct is defined as in https://docs.libreoffice.org/avmedia/html/Types_8hxx_source.html

```
struct libvlc_event_t
{
    int   type;  // event type
    void *p_obj; // object emitting that event

    union // so far we don't need this.
    {
     struct {
        const char *dummy1;
        const char *dummy2;
      } padding;
    } u;
};
```

then, the compatible struct in `go` will be:

```
type VLCEvent struct {
    Type      int32
    Pad_cgo_0 [4]byte
    Obj       *byte
    U         [16]byte
}

//Cast C struct to Go struct
ev := (*VLCEvent)(unsafe.Pointer(event))

//Cast Go struct to C struct
p := (*C.clibvlc_event_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&VLCEvent{}))
```

**EDIT:**
Add example struct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm just wondering why should I aliasing `libvlc_event_t` to `clibvlc_event_t`?

Comment: @tarrsalah Actually if the argument doesn't have `const` qualifier, you can access the `C` struct through `C.struct_libvlc_event_t`. Since `go` doesn't have `const` qualifier, `typedef` is one workaround. Here I choose `clibvlc_event_t` to denotes that this type has `const` qualifier. You can use `libvlc_event_t`. Another solution is creating another callback function in `C` without `const` qualifier.

Comment: Your answer and your comments are very helpful, thank you.